# FFTW, simple derivative in fortran

Tags: fortran, fftw, derivative

I am struggling with this simple derivative of a sine with FFTW. At a first look it seems ok but then there is a quite big error (5e-6) when compared with the exact solution...
I do see that after taking the c2r the complex input is all messed up, but it seems to me that same complex input is the cause of my problem... What am I doing wrong? I didn't use any pointer and tried to keep everything as simple as possible; still I can't figure out what's wrong.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!!!

```
program main
! C binding
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
implicit none

double precision, parameter :: pi = 4*ATAN(1.0)
complex, parameter :: ii =(0.0,1.0)

integer(C_INT), parameter :: Nx = 32
integer(C_INT), parameter :: Ny = Nx
double precision, parameter :: Lx = 2*pi, Ly = 2*pi
! Derived paramenter
double precision, parameter :: dx = Lx/Nx, dy = Ly/Ny

real(C_DOUBLE), dimension(Nx,Ny) :: x,y, u0,in,dudx,dudxE, errdU
real(C_DOUBLE), dimension(Nx/2+1,Ny) :: kx, ky

! Fourier space variables
complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), dimension(Nx/2+1,Ny) :: u_hat_x, out
! indices
integer :: i, j
!---FFTW plans
type(C_PTR) :: pf, pb

! FFTW include
include 'fftw3.f03'

write(*,'(A)') 'Starting...'

! Grid
forall(i=1:Nx,j=1:Ny)
    x(i,j) = (i-1)*dx
    y(i,j) = (j-1)*dy
end forall

! Compute the wavenumbers
forall(i=1:Nx/2,j=1:Ny) kx(i,j)=2*pi*(i-1)/Lx
kx(Nx/2+1,:) = 0.0
forall(i=1:Nx/2+1,j=1:Ny/2) ky(i,j)=2*pi*(j-1)/Ly
forall(i=1:Nx/2+1,j=Ny/2+1:Ny) ky(i,j)=2*pi*(j-Ny-1)/Ly

! Initial Condition
u0 = sin(2*x)
dudxE = 2*cos(2*x)

! Go to Fourier Space
in = u0
pf = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(Ny, Nx, in,out ,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
call fftw_execute_dft_r2c(pf,in,out)
u_hat_x = out

! Derivative
out = ii*kx*out

! Back to physical space
pb = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(Ny, Nx, out,in,FFTW_ESTIMATE)
call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(pb,out,in)

! rescale
dudx = in/Nx/Ny

! check the derivative
errdU = dudx - dudxE

! Write file
write(*,*) 'Writing to files...'

OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE="out_for.dat", ACTION="write", STATUS="replace", &
   FORM="unformatted")
WRITE(1) kx,u0,dudx,errdU,abs(u_hat_x)
CLOSE(UNIT=1)

call fftw_destroy_plan(pf)
call fftw_destroy_plan(pb)

write(*,'(A)') 'Done!'

end program main
```

Comment: This `pi = 4*ATAN(1.0)` is problematic, as you want pi to be double precision, but it will be converted from single precision, you need to use something like `pi = 4*ATAN(1.0_8)`, or better something like `pi = 4*ATAN(1.0_C_DOUBLE)` or `pi = 4*ATAN(1.0d0)`. This is because the `ATAN` function returns the same precision as the argument, and the constant `1.0` without any `_kind` suffix is just a single precision real variable.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but why all the 2D arrays? You're doing a 1D derivative (d/dx) of a function, why not use just 1D arrays?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll try changing the definition of pi, but I don't think that cause my problem, since if I FFT and IFFT the results are good. Also the error I get has a pattern, it looks very much like a Gibbs error, high frequency oscillations next to the boundary in the x-direction (the one with respect i'm deriving)

The 1D works fine, but I will need 2D, and I was starting from something more simple to get it straight before diving in complicated functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

steabert was right! the problem was simply with the pi definition which was only single precision! Thank you so much!